# Atlas position control performance inconsistant across machines

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I recently observed a significant difference in performance running the Atlas position control plugin on two different machines. On one machine, the robot stands stably at the zero position. On the other, the robot has a qualitatively different response and falls over immediately.

The setup on both machines is identical (and both are using drcsim 1.3.1 and gazebo 1.3.1). The only discernible difference between the machines are the speed at which the simulation runs---something that should not affect a controller running on simulation time.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this and how it can be fixed? I'd be happy to provide the PD gains I used in this test.

Thanks!

```
--sk
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/779/atlas-position-control-performance-inconsistant-across-machines/) by [scottk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/127/scottk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's been a lot of changes and bug fixes since drcsim 1.3.1, please try installing [gazebo 1.8.x](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Change_log#Gazebo_1.8.7_.282013-07-16.29) and [drcsim 2.6.x](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Change_log#drcsim_2.6.6_.282013-06-13.29). There's a good chance this was one of the startup race condition that was fixed some time ago.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0